# Erro ao consultar algumas palavras utilizando caractere curinga porcentagem (%)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

Olá.
Estou fazendo algumas consultas ao banco de dados que utiliza o PDO.
Quando eu faço a consulta sem o `%` no início da condição, os resultados retornam corretamente.

Ex.:

```
$localizacoes = $localizacao->find("nome LIKE :nome", "nome={$consultaLocalizacao}%")->order('nome')->limit($paginator->limit())->offset($paginator->offset())->fetch(true);
```

Contudo, quando eu apenas acrescento o `%` no início da condição, em algumas palavras buscadas retornam erro.

Ex.:

```
$localizacoes = $localizacao->find("nome LIKE :nome", "nome=%{$consultaLocalizacao}%")->order('nome')->limit($paginator->limit())->offset($paginator->offset())->fetch(true);
```

Erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xba in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sioepsul/vendor/coffeecode/datalayer/src/DataLayer.php on line 224

Isso acontece quando eu busco as palavras iniciando com: `ba, be, ca, ce, fa, fe`, entre outras. Modifica apenas o byte sequence para: `0xba, 0xbe, 0xca 0x25, 0xce 0x25, 0xfa, 0xfe`. O componente DataLayer (CoffeeCode) apenas faz o `execute()` do PDO, não acredito que seja problema nele.
Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: O problema é que o valor está sendo passado literal. Precisa escapar os % na definição do par. Teria como por os % depois: `find("nome LIKE CONCAT('%',:nome,'%')` mas só mascara outro problema. Sempre que fizer uma postagem, em vez do seu trecho original, forneça um [mcve] do problema para detectar a origem do problema.  Para aproveitar melhor o site vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: O problema foi resolvido utilizando a solução 1 apresentada pelo @eduardo-bissi

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. De qq forma, veja os links passados pra facilitar um feedback mais rápido nas próximas postagens, entender e aproveitar melhor a filosofia do site. E cuidado com libs de terceiros, muitas vezes elas geram mais problema do que solução a médio prazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comportamento é causado pelo `find`. No código ele usa a função `parse_str` ([fonte](https://github.com/robsonvleite/datalayer/blob/6a51fa227bba003be11519e7efa8338bc87460f5/src/DataLayer.php#L135)).

No [manual da função](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php) ela possui a seguinte descrição:

> Converte str como se ela tivesse sido passada via URL ...

Isto significa que irá "parsear" a string usando a codificação por cento. Assim, quando o *parser* encontrar o sinal de % ele pega os dois próximos caracteres e interpreta como se fosse um hexadecimal (%ba vira 0xba).

Associa-se a isto o fato do php [trabalhar com as strings na forma binária](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details), sem se "importar" se representa um caractere válido na codificação. Assim ele envia uma sequencia de bytes ao PostgreSQL onde é validado e confirmado que não existe um caractere em UTF-8 começando com o byte passado.

Dá pra testar usando o [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php). Por exemplo, no navegador, `urldecode("nome=%ba%")` retorna `"nome=�%"`.

Solução 1 - usar o `%` em codificação url `%25`:

```
$localizacoes = $localizacao->find("nome LIKE :nome", "nome=%25{$consultaLocalizacao}%25")->order('nome')->limit($paginator->limit())->offset($paginator->offset())->fetch(true);
```

Solução 2 - não usar `LIKE`, usar `~` ou `~*` ([Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)):

```
$localizacoes = $localizacao->find("nome ~* :nome", "nome={$consultaLocalizacao}")->order('nome')->limit($paginator->limit())->offset($paginator->offset())->fetch(true);
```

Na solução 2 a consulta se comporta como expressão regular *case insensitive*, mas pode te dar alguma dor de cabeça se na pesquisa contiver caracteres que são usados em expressões regulares, como `.`, `*`, `(`, `)` etc.

Comment: Caramba, utilizei a solução 1 e funcionou perfeitamente e me fizeste entender a raiz do problema. Muito obrigado, Eduardo.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. Aproveitando, eu estava pensando aqui que, dependendo de como você trata `$consultaLocalizacao`, se o usuário incluir um sinal de % na pesquisa pode ser que o problema apareça de novo. Faça seus testes.

Comment: @EduardoBissi e precisa ver se não tem interpolação ou concatenação direta de strings, para garantir que não tenha superficie para injection. Como você viu detalhes da lib, acho que já tem como avaliar. Se fosse um bind puro de valor direto no DB, não teria problema, mas sendo pelo PDO + libs extras, nunca se sabe.